# Design functor to be able to use different modules

Tags: coq

I have two different module signatures into two different files. They have the same field name but different behaviour.

And functor inside define another functor.

```
PI.v

Module Type TPI.
  Parameter sig : Signature.
  Parameter trsInt: forall f, pi f.
End TPI.

Module P (Export T: TPI).
   Lemma A...
    Module Export Mono <: MonoType.
End P.
```

and

```
MI.v

Module Type TMI.
   Parameter sig : Signature.
   Parameter trsInt : forall f, mi f.
End TMI.

Module M (Export TM: TMI).
   Lemma B ...
   Module Export Mono <: MonoType.
End M.
```

Where `MonoType` inside another file for example `Mono.v`

Here is my situation.

I have another file called `B.v` inside that file I need to use definitions and lemmas in both files `PI.v` and `MI.v`.

And one definition I need to use both of them for example.

```
 Definition redPair R is :=
   match is with
 | Type_PI => pi_int R is
 | Type_MI => mi_int R is
 end.
```

I have a problem at `R` because `pi_int R` and `mi_int R` has different `sig` (Signature), where `pi_int` used `trsInt` inside the module signature `TPI` and `mint_int` used `trsInt` inside the module signature `TMI`.

Here is the way I defined it:

```
Module PI (Import P : TPI).
Definition pi_int R is := P.trsInt ...

(* inside PI I define another functor for MI *)
  Module MI (Import M : TMI).
   Definition mi_int R is := M.trsInt ...

   Definition redPair R is :=  
     match is with
    | Type_PI => pi_int R is
    | Type_MI => mi_int R is  (* error here saying that it used the sig of 
                    P.sig but in this case mi_int used the sig of M.sig *)
    end.

End MI.
End PI.
```

My question is that is there a way that I can have a good structure of module that I can have the same signature at the definition `redPair`? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, in the definition of `redPair`, you have no guarantee that `P.sig` and `M.sig` have the same type, which is why you get this error message.

What one can do to solve this kind of problem is to enforce the type equality via a "sharing constraint". Here is a code similar to yours demonstrating how I force `P.sig` and `M.sig` to be equal to `nat`:

```
Module Type TPI.
  Parameter sig : Type.
  Parameter x : sig.
End TPI.

Module Type TMI.
  Parameter sig : Type.
  Parameter x : sig.
End TMI.

Module PI (Import P : TPI with Definition sig := nat).
  Definition pi_int := x.

  Module MI (Import M : TMI with Definition sig := nat).
    Definition mi_int := x.

    Definition f (x : bool) :=
      if x
      then pi_int
      else mi_int.

  End MI.

End PI.
```

You could also choose to leave `P.sig` unconstrained, but then enforce `M.sig` to be the same:

```
Module PI (Import P : TPI).
  Definition pi_int := x.

  Module MI (Import M : TMI with Definition sig := P.sig).
    Definition mi_int := x.

    Definition f (x : bool) :=
      if x
      then pi_int
      else mi_int.

  End MI.

End PI.
```

---

Now that a solution to your problem is mentioned, I would advise to be wary of using modules and functors in Coq. Most often than not, you actually only need dependent records. Modules and functors are complicated for everyone, you have to care about abstraction, sharing constraints, etc.

The status quo seems to be that you should avoid using them unless you *actually* need them for what they offer over dependent records: abstraction and/or subtyping.

As a matter of fact, I am at a bit of unease with your definitions right now. For instance, does it make sense for `MI` to be defined inside of `PI`? That seems arbitrary without more context. Maybe it does, I'm just stating that you should be careful when using modules, and make sure you have a good grasp of what you're doing, or it might backfire on you! :)

But if you're just experimenting, please do experiment with them. It's good to know the range of possibilities and the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Thank you!!! You are right! I can do it with Record. But because I am using the library that provided by Module structure. Thank you very much for your help. I chose the second one, it works now. :)